# Python space in xml element text when using "&"

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I have a script which pulls XML hosted online and saves it locally. The script then goes through the local file and replaces/adds certain text. However, for some reason, when I use the "&" symbol, there is an extra space inserted along with it within the element text. Here is a sample of the XML elements I am parsing:

```
<TrackingEvents>
<Tracking event="rewind">
http://www.example.com/rewind_1.png?test=rewind_test 
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="pause">
http://www.example.com/pause_1.png?test=rewind_test 
</Tracking>
```

However, after running my script to add the additional test to my elements, the text is added with an additional space, like this:

```
<TrackingEvents>
<Tracking event="rewind">
http://www.example.com/rewind_1.png?test=rewind_test &cb={CACHEBUSTER}
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="pause">
http://www.example.com/pause_1.png?test=rewind_test &cb={CACHEBUSTER}
</Tracking>
```

I have tried everything but I don't know why this is occurring or what I can do to prevent this space from being added. I have even tried to strip the white space as well. When I look at the XML that is saved locally before uploading it, everything looks fine (& is for the "&" symbol) as seen here from the source:

```
<Tracking event="rewind">
http://www.example.com/rewind_1.png?test=rewind_test
&amp;cb={CACHEBUSTER}</Tracking>
                        <Tracking event="pause">
http://www.example.com/pause_1.png?test=rewind_test
&amp;cb={CACHEBUSTER}</Tracking>
```

Here is what the code from my script looks like:

```
for URL, xml_name, original_server in tqdm(XML_tags):
    response = requests.get(URL)
    with open(xml_name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
    with open(xml_name) as saved_file:
    tree = ET.parse(saved_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for element in root.iter(tag=ET.Element):
    if element.text != None:
        if ".png" in element.text:
            if "?" in element.text:
                element.text = element.text + "&cb={CACHEBUSTER}"
                element.text = element.text.strip()
            else:
                element.text = element.text + "?cb={CACHEBUSTER}"
                element.text = element.text.strip()
        else:
            pass

    server = "example.server: ../sample/sample/" + original_server
    tree.write(xml_name, xml_declaration=True, method='xml', 
    encoding='utf8')
    server_upload = subprocess.Popen(["scp", xml_name, server])
    upload_wait = os.waitpid(server_upload.pid, 0)
```

I can definitely use some help with this. Thanks.

Update: Actually, it appears that this has nothing to do with using the "&". Here is a sample when I just add different text:

```
<TrackingEvents>
<Tracking event="rewind">
http://www.example.com/rewind_1.png?test=rewind_test test123
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="pause">
http://www.example.com/pause_1.png?test=rewind_test test123
</Tracking>
</TrackingEvents>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitespace was in the original XML even before you add anything to `element.text`; it is the newline between the *last letter in the `.text`* and the *closing tag*. So you should have removed the whitespace before appending text instead of after appending as you did in your code above :

```
....
if "?" in element.text:
    element.text = element.text.strip() + "&cb={CACHEBUSTER}"
else:
    element.text = element.text.strip() + "?cb={CACHEBUSTER}"
....
```

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right about the newline being there the whole time... striping the '\n' fixes the issue. Thanks.